# Hibernate gives 'table is not mapped' Exception

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I configured package which contains pojo entity class which defined tables.

However, I see errors from below query

```
public interface TargetRepository extends CrudRepository<TargetEntity, String> {
    @Query("SELECT a, b FROM target_table")
    public List<Object> selectTargets();
}
```

org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: target_table is not mapped

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Your query is just wrong. You don't specify name of table as in `SQL` database. You specify name of table as name of entity in your application. So, it should be something like:

```
@Query("select te from TargetEntity te")
List<TargetEntity> selectTargets();
```

Also, as far as I see, your query is supposed to fetch all targets. Therefore, you could just define method:

```
List<TargetEntity> findAll();
```

and voila! Magic! It will fetch all records from your `table_target` table.